# LPTHW Ex 43 queries on use of self

Tags: python-2.7, oop

From [Learn Python the Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex43.html), I am slightly confused by what the below code does. What exactly do the following few lines of code do?

1. For this line,

   ```
   current_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene(next_scene_name)
   ```

   I believe this gets from value of `CentralCorridor()` using the `central_corridor` key from the dictionary. So it would look something like this:

   ```
   current_scene = self.scene_map.CentralCorridor()
   ```

   What exactly does the `self.scene_map` do?
2. For this line,

   ```
   return self.next_scene(self.start_scene)
   ```

   Why is it necessary to specify the `self` in front of `next_return`? Why can't it be as follows?

   ```
   return next_scene(self.start_scene)
   ```

**Engine block**

```
class Engine(object):

    def __init__(self, scene_map):
        self.scene_map = scene_map

    def play(self):
        current_scene = self.scene_map.opening_scene()
        last_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene('finished')
        print "K Engine current_scene", current_scene
        print "K Engine last_scene", last_scene

        while current_scene != last_scene:
            next_scene_name = current_scene.enter()
            current_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene(next_scene_name)
            print "K Engine next_scene_name", next_scene_name

        # be sure to print out the last scene
        current_scene.enter()
```

**Map block**

```
class Map(object):

    scenes = {
        'central_corridor': CentralCorridor(),
        'laser_weapon_armory': LaserWeaponArmory(),
        'the_bridge': TheBridge(),
        'escape_pod': EscapePod(),
        'death': Death(),
        'finished': Finished(),
    }

    def __init__(self, start_scene):
        self.start_scene = start_scene

    # For the key "scene_name", get its value from scenes dictionary located in Map class.
    def next_scene(self, scene_name):
        val = Map.scenes.get(scene_name)
        print "K Map val", val
        return val

    def opening_scene(self):
        print "K Map opening_scene", self.next_scene(self.start_scene)
        return self.next_scene(self.start_scene)

a_map = Map('central_corridor')
a_game = Engine(a_map)
a_game.play()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First question

I think the best way, after your read through the implementation of the classes, is to start at the end where the execution begins:

```
a_map = Map('central_corridor')
a_game = Engine(a_map)
a_game.play()
```

So `a_map` is an instance of `Map` and gets `'central_corridor'` stored in `self.start_scene` (see `__init__()` of `Map`). Next, `a_game = Engine(a_map)` makes an instance of `Engine` handing in this instance `a_map`. It is stored in `self.scene_map` (see `__init__()` of `Engine`). Calling `play()` on this instance finally comes to this line:

```
current_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene(next_scene_name)
```

It means:

```
current_scene = CentralCorridor()
```

because it retrieves an instance of `CentralCorridor` from the dictionary `scenes` in `Map`, using the key `'central_corridor'` via the method `next_scene` of `Map`.

The method `next_scene()` can only be reached via the class `Map` or an instance of this class. In `Engine` such an instance is stored in `self.scene_map`. Therefore, you need to use `self.scene_map.next_scene()`. Just using `next_scene(next_scene_name)` will give you a `NameError` because there is no such function defined. Again, methods in a class are not visible throughout the whole module. They can only be accessed via a class or an instance.

### Second question

While this line works:

```
return self.next_scene(self.start_scene)
```

this line does not work:

```
return next_scene(self.start_scene)
```

because the method `next_scene` is defined in the class `Map`. It is not a normal function in the global module space. You can call it either via the class `Map.next_scene(a_map, 'name_of_scene')` (not often done) or via the instance  `a_map.next_scene('name_of_scene')`. The `self` stands for any instance. Therefore, in this case you call `a_map.next_scene('name_of_scene')`.

Comment: Hi Mike Müller, many thanks for your quick reply. Would like to clarify the following. When you say "It is stored in self.scene_map". What exactly is stored in there? Would it be 'central_corridor'?

Comment: I still have difficulties understanding the first question. Could you please explain why `current_scene = next_scene(next_scene_name)` would not work? Doesn't `next_scene(next_scene_name)` already retrieve `CentralCorridor()` from the dictionary? What is the purpose of the additional `self.scene_map` in the front.

Comment: Because there is no function `next_scene()`, only a method with this name in `Map`. For accessing this method in `Engine` you need to have an instance of `Map`, which is `self.scene_map` in `Engine`. See my updated answer.

Comment: Hi Mark, thank you so much for the detailed response. Really appreciate your input. Had been struggling with this the whole weekend. This finally made sense! Thanks once again.